# Flyway migration, Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource

Tags: mysql, maven, jdbc, flyway

I am trying to use flyway to create and manage a MySQL database. Here is the code i have got so far.

FlywayMigration.java : Class that applys the migration

```
public class FlywayMigration
{
    public FlywayMigration(DatabaseConfiguration configuration, Flyway flyway)
    {
        flyway.setDataSource(configuration.getDataSource());
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new FlywayMigration(new DatabaseConfiguration("database.properties"), new Flyway());
    }
}
```

DatabaseConfiguration.java : Configuration class, this class will configure the datasource to be applyed to the Flyway.setDataSource method

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration
{
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private PropertiesUtil prop = null;

    public DatabaseConfiguration(String file)
    {
        prop = new PropertiesUtil(file);
    }

    public String getDataSourceClass()
    {
        return prop.getProperty("mysql.data.source.class");
    }

    public String getURL ()
    {
        return prop.getProperty("mysql.url");
    }

    public String getHostName()
    {
        return prop.getProperty("mysql.host.name");
    }

    public String getDatabaseName()
    {
        return prop.getProperty("mysql.database.name");
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(getURL());
        dataSource.setUser(prop.getProperty("mysql.user.name"));
        dataSource.setPassword(null);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

database.properties is the file where i store the database information, password can be null

```
mysql.data.source.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver    
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vmrDB    
mysql.host.name=localhost    
mysql.database.name=vmrDB    
mysql.user.name=root
```

And i get the folowing error in my trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1144)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:811)
    at com.bt.sitb.vmr.migration.FlywayMigration.<init>(FlywayMigration.java:10)
    at com.bt.sitb.vmr.migration.FlywayMigration.main(FlywayMigration.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Can someone please tell me why the DataSource from MySQL is not connecting?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like Flyway cannot connect to the database.

One reason for this is that the database in the database URL does not exist.

Question: does your database schema exist?

If your answer is no, then:

- connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**mysql**
- also specify the schema to use for migration with `flyway.setSchemas(configuration.getDatabaseName())`
- you also need `flyway.init()` before you can initialize migration of your database.

Comment: ran into this using ninja framework + flyway. Had to append /postgres when connecting to AWS RDS instance

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when working on a Java application in Debian 10 using Tomcat Application server.

I defined the connection strings for the database in the context.xml file, however, when I start out the application and try to log into the application, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource

> at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)

> at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1144)

**Here's what I figured out**:

I finally realized that the application was using **internally defined database connection strings** that were packaged with it. The internally defined database connection strings were different from my own database connection strings defined in the `context.xml` file.

The solution for me was to either modify the **internally defined database connection strings** that were packaged with the application or use the same internally defined database connection strings that were packaged with application in my `context.xml` file.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue. Apparently, the problem was with my `.properties` file. The jar was using the one packaged with it and not the external one. So I moved my external properties file out of the resources folder and into the root directory of the jar and problem solved! 
Hope this helps someone.